# How much overhead does the Chinese firewall add to a network conversation?

Tags: networking, performance, latency

Does anyone have any stats on this?

I'm mainly asking from a private network perspective (assuming that they are affected by the firewall as well).  That is, all of my apps that are in use in China are on our internal network.

I got to thinking about this after reading  [**Mr Denny's recent answer on SQL replication**](https://serverfault.com/questions/69388/should-i-avoid-sql-server-replication/69397#69397).  Now I'm wondering how much of a hit my app is taking in China because of the firewall.

Comment: Are you asking about Youth Escort Green Dam, or the national infrastructure firewall?

Comment: I'd be far more concerned about what kind of latency their firewall creates on freedom of information, buuuuut that's a topic for another day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was working on it, we calculated round trip at 550ms, with about 250ms of the time being native network lag time, about about 300-350ms of time being spent on the firewall.

This was over a T1 with no traffic on it (it was dedicated to SQL Replication traffic).

Comment: Bah, in Australia a < 500ms ping to anywhere is not bad, < 200 is awesome and < 100 is unheard of. You get used to it.

Comment: Ouch.  That's brutal.  Guess there's not a lot of high traffic stuff going in or out of Australia without some major pain.

Answer (score 0):

Bruce Schneier [commented](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2006/06/ignoring_the_gr.html) on an [article](http://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/2006/06/27/ignoring-the-great-firewall-of-china/) about how the firewall works and how to circumvent it. Warranted, the article is from 2006, so things might have changed, but it's a worthwhile read nonetheless.

Besides the closed TCP connections, I'm not aware of any other practices that the Chinese use with their firewall, so connections shouldn't incur too much more of a penalty. The added latency of connections to China are more likely due too the distance traveled than the firewall.